# How to force checking internet reachability using Reachability.m/.h

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reachability, network-connection

I'm using Reachability.m/.h to check internet/wifi status. Everything is working great with the Library, I get a notification every time the status changed thanks to the notifier and the observer but sometimes (rarely but still, sometimes) the status doesn't change.

In some part of my code I need to "force" the checking of the reachability. Is there any way I can do that with the class Reachability.m/.h?

Comment: check my answer, if it helps you don't forget to accept it, also if it needs more clarifications just let me know, good luck

Comment: If you want to try a Swift native version of Reachability, you could take a look at https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift - this might work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method named `connected` :

```
- (BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
```

Use it like this when you want to force check the reachability :

```
if (![self connected]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No connection" message:@"you have to be connected in order to continue" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"no connection");
    } else {
// the user is connected , write your code here
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks great but It's not working. When I make the test : if(! [self connected]) I can enter in the "if" even if I have no network connection... So, for example, I can enter the "if" while I'll have Parse error like : Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Comment: you can use a method like this to handle it:

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
      NSLog(@"connection didFailWithError");
   if(error.code==-1009){

      // show an alert to the user to tell him to connect to the internet  

   }

}

Comment: I did this but still, I never enter the "didFailWithError" method even if I have the -1009 error. Should I add something in the info.plist ? Or do I have to init something ?